# Empty items on Flipview using Itemsource

Tags: c#, uwp, flipview

I am trying to load a folder full of images into a Flipview, if that folder is inside the project itself there is no problem, but if i try with a different location, the Fliview is loaded with empty items.

XAML:

```
<FlipView x:Name="FVtest" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="750" Height="750">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />               
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public async void Funcion (){

        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker()
        {
            ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads,
            SettingsIdentifier = "Setting"
        };
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(folder.Name, folder);

        String path = folder.Path; //getting the path of a folder selected by the user
        String path2 = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Images"; //This one works

        FVtest.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles(path2); 
    }
```

Besides the initial problem, is this an efficient approach?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to get all the image files, we should add the image `FileTypeFilter`, such as `.png` and `.jpg` and use the [StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfilesasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_GetFilesAsync) Method to get all the image files, then we can show all the images.

Here is the code example:

```
public async void Funcion()
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker()
    {
        ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
        SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads,
        SettingsIdentifier = "Setting"
    };
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(folder.Name, folder);
    ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> sourceImage = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView);
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(thumbnail);
            sourceImage.Add(bitmap);
        }
    }
    //String path = folder.Path; //getting the path of a folder selected by the user
    //String path2 = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Images"; //This one works

    FVtest.ItemsSource = sourceImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that approach load every image in memory and then add its to the FlipView (i tested it, without using thumbails, and in 10 relatively big images used more that 500 mb).

Comment: @Micheleuno Firstly, I should point out that the [Path in UWP apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/)  and our app can access the files in the app's install directory **path2** directly, that is the different between **path** and **path2**.
Besides, it seems unreasonable to display many big images in one time and still don't want to cost much memory resources. See the topic [Optimize image resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-animations-and-media#optimize-image-resources).

Comment: I was mostly curious about that approach (i saw it on an guide somewhere). Currently i'm doing something simmilar to your example but  adding one BitmapImage on every "SelectionChanged" of the Flipview, reducing the initial amount of Ram used. I will read that last article, looks quite interesting,